# Inspect Element - CSS hover over

Tags: wordpress, debugging, element, inspect

Anybody have any tips on trying to change the color of the content background on the Icons when you hover over them and the content box shows up.

I just can't seem to  inspect the area, because I cant get my mouse to inspect the background because it vanishes once my cursor is actually on it.

Screenshot - http://postimg.org/image/cspn2nxf5/full/

http://techwizdesign.com/cap/homecap/

Comment: Use `firefox with firubug`. In this you can select in right hand side. Style->hover. It's mean. It's not get hide when you mouse hover and out.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see this is being generated in the DOM

```
<a href="http://techwizdesign.com/cap/contact-us/" class="av-icon-char" style="font-size:100px;line-height:100px;width:100px;" aria-hidden="true" data-av_icon="" data-av_iconfont="entypo-fontello" data-avia-icon-tooltip="
<ol>
<li>Contact Us</li>
<li>Get a Quote</li>
<li>Upload a File</li>
</ol>
"></a>
```

If you look at the closing body tag you'll find this block which the javascript turns on and off - style at will

```
<div class="avia-tooltip avia-icon-tooltip avia-tt" style="left: 591.1875px; top: 309px;  opacity: 0; display: none; "><div class="inner_tooltip">
<ol>
<li>Contact Us</li>
<li>Get a Quote</li>
<li>Upload a File</li>
</ol>
</div><span class="avia-arrow-wrap"><span class="avia-arrow"></span></span></div>
```